# The reason of being feminine in `a su derecha`?

Tags: sustantivos

I've encountered the following sentences in my Rosetta Stone Spanish program:

```
El teatro está a su derecha.
El café está a su izquierda.
```

On the two sentences above, why do these use feminine nouns? Both `teatro` and `café` are masculine nouns, if it is related.

Also, the photos on the program seem to use the masculine to imply `su`. So I don't know any reasons to use feminine nouns here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the sentences you provide, *izquierda* and *derecha* are nouns, and are not bound to *teatro* and *café*. Like in many languages, the same words can be used as adjectives, and when they are used in that way, they will agree in gender with the nouns they modify (e.g., *al lado derecho*).

But in this case, they are being used as nouns, specifically as objects of a preposition (to his/her/their *left*, to his/her/their *right*), and in Spanish, these particular nouns are feminine.

Comment: So you mean that it is a rule that if you want to express locations, you have to use feminine nouns, right?

Comment: Well, not exactly. It just means that the nouns _la izquierda_ and _la derecha_ are feminine. You could pick a location that is masculine: _El teatro está al lado_, meaning _The Theater is on the side_ (omitting which side, to avoid confusing the illustration).

Comment: Ah, alright. It looks like I was convinced that if a noun can be expressed in both masculine and feminine, the masculine form is prioritized. But this rule depends on each word, doesn't it? Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Again, not really. A noun is either masculine or feminine. Don't confuse the nouns (left and right) with the adjectives (left and right) that just happen to have the same spelling, and similar/related meanings. Grammatically, they serve different purposes. The third person possessive pronoun (_su_) simply does not convey gender, but it doesn't mean the noun can be either masculine or feminine.

Comment: @Gardecolo unless a noun refers to a biological entity, don't try to interpret anything from the gender. Nouns that refer to inanimate things have the gender they do... simply "because". There's no particular reason that the nouns right/left in Spanish are both feminine. Notice the synonym for *LA izquierda* is masculine: *el siniestro*. And in fact *el derecho* exists, but it means rights (as in civil rights) or law, but when used as a direction it means the place in front of you in many countries.

Comment: @guifa Be careful: *el siniestro* is not a synonym for *la izquierda*. A *siniestro* is a damage caused by an accident. A synonym for *la izquierda* would be *la siniestra*, feminine.

Comment: A likely reason for *derecha* and *izquierda* being feminine is that they take their gender from *mano*. *A la derecha* has the same meaning as *a mano derecha*.

Answer (score 2):

Nouns do not have to agree in gender.  For example:

> The man is in the house.
>   El hombre está en la casa

`El hombre` is masculine and `la casa` is feminine.

Answer (score 0):

We do not agree nouns in Spanish; apart from that, posesive adjectives (apart from nuestro and nuestra) do not agree in gender either, only in number. Whenever you want to express location, feminine is used with these words.

```
Voltee a la derecha.
No veo nada a mi izquierda.
```

However, it is possible to say "derecho" as an adjective:

```
Tu brazo izquierdo está bien.
Encontrará el libro al lado derecho del estante.
```

Comment: Eso no es del todo cierto: suyo / suya, mío / mía... El género sí que cambia, la distinción es, con qué concuerda? Con el sujeto (esta casa es suya, este coche es mío) Por tanto tu explicación no es del todo cierto. Tendrías que decir adjetivos determinativos posesivos, y aún así, en la primera persona del plural (nuestro) que no hay forma apócope (si así se puede considerar la distinción de un posesivo adj. y pronombre) también varía en género, pero no dependiendo del poseedor, sino del objeto poseído.

Comment: Correcto, ¡gracias por la corrección!